# How to treat sequential numerical optimization (bilevel optimization)?

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to understand how to set up sequential optimization problems. I first want to understand how to treat a basic problem like

\begin{equation}
\max_{x \in \Omega} f(x,m(x))
\quad
\text{with}
\quad
m(x) = \max_{y}g(x,y)
\end{equation}

In my actual problem, I have very complicated nonlinear vector functions and several constraints building the set $\Omega$.

But, let us consider an example with
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x,m(x)) &=& \sin(x)m(x)
\ , \\
m(x) &=& \max_{y} g(x,y)
\ , \\
g(x,y) &=& -(y-\sin(x))^2+\cos(x)
\ , \\
\Omega &=& \{x \ | \ 0 \leq x \leq \pi \}
\end{eqnarray}
Naturally, $m(x) = \cos(x)$ and $\max_{x \in \Omega}f = 1/2$ for $x=\pi/4 \approx 0.785398$ holds. But suppose you dont have an analytical solution for the maximum of $g$ in respect to $y$ (due to high nonlinearity) and you want to treat the problem numerically.

**How would you approach this problem numerically?**

My attempt is to define all functions with numerical arguments and use `NMaxValue` and `NMaximize`, but this takes forever (around 17 mins on my laptop) already for this 1D problem.

```
g[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := -(y - Sin[x])^2 + Cos[x];
m[x_?NumericQ] := NMaxValue[g1[x, y], y];
Omega = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= Pi, x];
f[x_?NumericQ] := Sin[x]*m[x];
DateString[]
NMaximize[{f[x], 0 <= x <= Pi}, x]
DateString[]
DateDifference[t1, t2, {"Minute", "Second"}]
```

> "Sat 30 Dec 2017 15:17:01"
>
> {0.5, {x -> 0.785398}}
>
> "Sat 30 Dec 2017 15:33:54"
>
> 16 min 53 s

**EDIT:**
I just learned, that this kind of problems is referred to as bilevel optimization, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilevel_optimization). How do you treat these problems with Mathematica?

Comment: I am curious what your actual optimization problem is. Would you mind to elaborate on it a bit?

Comment: Sadly, right now I only have my phone with me. I will try to find this week a compact form for my problem and post it.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I wont be able to post my actual problem here. I have been trying to find a compact description for my actual problem, but it contains several high-order tensors, `f` is a very large expression and I would have to introduce too much stuff. Further, my `g` functions are not concave and have several maxima. But I think I have just came up with an artificial constraint which helps me define implicitly my maxima for my special `g`. Still, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the maxima of `g` is in the interior and not on a boundary, one can use the constraint $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=0$. Then, the maxima can be obtained with:

```
Maximize[{f[x, g[x, y]], Derivative[0, 1][g][x, y] == 0}, {x, y}] //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{\frac{1}{2},\left\{x\to -2 \left(24 \pi -\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{4+3 \sqrt{2}}{-2-\sqrt{2}}\right)\right),y\to
>    \frac{2 \left(-1-\sqrt{2}\right)}{1+\left(-1-\sqrt{2}\right)^2}\right\}\right\}$

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will check if I can use the stationarity condition as an additional constraint in my actual problem. Do you have any idea how to treat such problems if also conditions are imposed on $y$ and the maximum is obtained in the boundary of the corresponding constraint set for $y$, say $\Omega_y$? I will try to create an example for that.

Comment: @MauricioLobos If `g` is convex with respect to `y` and if the domain of definition of `g` is also concave (and some constraint qualification is satisfied) then the [Karush-Kuhn-Tucker-conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush–Kuhn–Tucker_conditions) are not only necessary but also sufficient. These can be used similarly to $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = 0$ as  constraints.

Comment: Together with optimality of `f`, this would lead to a system of semismooth equations that can be solved, e.g., with the semismooth Newton method (not hard to implement, actually I have some code for it somewhere). If the optimization problem for `g` is nonconvex in `y`, I had to think about it again...

Comment: @MauricioLobos Sorry: If it's about maximization then `g` being concave would make things much easier.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher thanks! I will check my g is concave and if the KKT conditions are applicabke to my case. Do you happend to have a reference for the application of semismooth Newton in bilevel optimization?

Comment: @MauricioLobos Actually no. =0/ It just came to my mind yesterday because it can be a very efficient way to solve the KKT conditions.

Comment: @CarlWoll, am I missing something but why `x` is so small in the result (in `g` it seems to be somewhere around 1)? I also cannot make this code working in 11. Could you provide `f` in your code, as in OP's `f` seems different.