# Bilevel optimization

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I found a problem [here](https://bi-level.org/introduction-to-bilevel-optimization/)
[image]

How do we go about solving this in Mathematica?  I did something like this:

```
NMinimize[(x^2 + y^2 - 1)^2, {x, y}]
```

this gives `{3.08149*10^-33, {x -> 0.865404, y -> 0.501074}}`

And used this `y -> 0.501074` and did this:

```
NMinimize[
 x^2 + 0.1*Cos[4 Pi x] + y^2 + 0.1*Sin[4 Pi y] /. 
  y -> 0.5010739136683062`, x]
```

which gave

`{0.207832, {x -> -0.221351}}`

**Edit:**
Actually, I had tried this method and meant to post it today but got late:

```
F[x_, y_] := x^2 + 0.1*Cos[4 Pi x] + y^2 + 0.1*Sin[4 Pi y];
g[x_, y_] := (x^2 + y^2 - 1)^2;

NMinimize[{F[x, g[x, y]], Derivative[0, 1][g][x, y] == 0}, {x, y}]
```

I got `{0.390615, {x -> -0.627901, y -> -0.778293}}`

If plot this then I get:[image]
This doesn't make sense

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combined numerical minimization and maximization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/333/combined-numerical-minimization-and-maximization)

Comment: (1) This has come up several times on MSE. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162833/how-to-treat-sequential-numerical-optimization-bilevel-optimization) or [this other](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40941/l-infty-norm-minimization) for examples. Also the one referenced in my "close as duplicate" vote, if this gets closed.

Comment: (2) Don't get me wrong, this is a reasonable type of inquiry. But it has several answers already.

Comment: Thanks @DanielLichtblau for all the links.  Actually, I had tried one of the methods that you mentioned and I just updated my post with an edit. I didn't get a sensible answer. May I am understanding the problem incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is a first, but I rarely answer a question I voted to close. In this case I found the wording of the problem to be convoluted (at least for me) so I opted to take a stab at it.

We need a function to do the inner optimization.

```
innerMin[x_?NumericQ] := 
 First[FindArgMin[{(x^2 + z^2 - 1)^2, 0 <= z <= 1}, {z, 1/2}]]
```

The actual objective function uses the inner optimization.

```
objFunc[x_] := 
 With[{y = innerMin[x]}, x^2 + 0.1*Cos[4 Pi x] + y^2 + 0.1*Sin[4 Pi y]]
```

Let's see what we get.

```
NMinimize[{objFunc[x], 0 <= x <= 1}, x]

(* Out[6]= {0.858145, {x -> 0.270149}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
F[x_, y_] = x^2 + 1/10*Cos[4 Pi x] + y^2 + 1/10*Sin[4 Pi y]

g[x_, y_] = (x^2 + y^2 - 1)

nmin = NMinimize[{F[x, y], g[x, y] == 0, 0 <= x <= 1, 
0 <= y <= 1}, {x, y}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]

Show[Plot3D[F[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, -.01 < g[x, y] < .01], 
PlotPoints -> 100], 
Graphics3D[{Red, 
Sphere[{x, y, F[x, y]} /. nmin[[2]], .03]}]]

sol = Flatten@
Solve[{g[x, y] == 0, 0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 1}, {x, y}, Reals]

(min = Minimize[{F[x, Sqrt[1 - x^2]], 0 <= x <= 1}, x, Reals])

Plot[F[x, Sqrt[1 - x^2]], {x, 0, 1}, 
GridLines -> {{x /. min[[2]]}, None}]
```

Comment: Isn't the definition of `g[x_,y_]` incorrect?

Comment: `y == ArgMin[{(x^2 + z^2 - 1)^2, 0 < z < 1 && 0 < x < 1}, z, Reals] // 
 FullSimplify[#, 0 < x < 1] & `  yields `Sqrt[1 - x^2] == y `  and `sol = Flatten@
  Solve[{g[x, y] == 0, 0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 1}, {x, y}, Reals] ` yields `{y -> ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[1 - x^2], 0 <= x <= 1]} `